# React Router v4 Redirect with parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route set up:

```
<Route path="/search/:name" component={foo} />
```

In a component I am trying to redirect based on the entered name:

```
<Redirect to="/search" />
```

I want to pass `this.state.name` to the Redirect, like `/search/name`. How?

Comment: If the `this.state.name` is available in the scope, you can simply write ``<Redirect to={`/search/${this.state.name}`} />``

Comment: When results are printed I get: Search results for ${this.state.name} as a string...

Comment: Ideally I would do: <Redirect to="/search" + this.state.name /> but React complains about that

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the comment. SO's formatting was a bit messed up. React complained because, you're writing JS code inside the JSX syntax. It needs to be enclosed in { }

Comment: This still isn't working - it's just printing out the result as a string

Comment: Are you sure you're utilizing the `params` from the `Route`'s props?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150403/discussion-between-giri-and-matt-saunders).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Resolved:

I had to wrap in curly braces like so:

```
<Redirect to={"/search/" + this.state.name} />
```

(Thanks to Giri for guidance)

Comment: No problem!. I see you got confused a bit while I was using backticks instead of quotes. Sorry about that!. But avoid these kind of string concatenation wherever possible by using the backticks. For more info,  [Have a look at this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)